# Avoid moving two views at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have several UIImageView as subview of a UIView that act as a canvas. The ImageViews receive touch events, so I can move them.
If I pan two views, each finger on each of them I can move two views at the same time. I don't want that.

I checked the maximumNumberOfTouches property on the superview but it affects that view, but it doesn't prevent that each other subview receives the touch event.

Any ideas how to avoid this behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just setting a flag that an image view is already moving, and the pan gesture on all views check that flag before actually moving their views? Just set the flag to false once the view has stopped moving.

Comment: Yes, set and check the flag in your view controller or the app delegate.

Comment: Thanks I decided to change the design of the app and have different view controllers, because actually I was working on tow conceptually different views. Anyway, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

you may do like this ,  extend UIImageView as a Custom UIView may called YouImageView

in the touch event

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for ( UIView *v in self.superview.subviews )
    {
        if ( v != self )
        {
            v.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for ( UIView *v in self.superview.subviews )
    {
        v.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

}
```

done!